# How to send a signedCookie in Jest test

Tags: node.js, express, cookies, jestjs

I am writing tests for my Node.js/express application, and I need to make requests to different APIs. The router requests takes in a signed cookie for some of the endpoints to authenticate the user trying to access said endpoint.

The problem is I am unable to find out how I mock a cookie with authentication details using Jest tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `cookie-parser` library uses the `cookie-signature` library under the hood. I'm assuming you have access to the encryption key or cookie secret (in .env or wherever). Without it, you can't sign your cookies.

I'm using `supertest` for requests.

```js
import request from 'supertest';
import { unsign } from 'cookie-signature';
// If your key comes from .env
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
dotenv.config();

const baseURL = 'http://localhost:3000';
const key = process.env.COOKIE_SECRET; // Set your key here. Mine comes from .env

describe('My super awesome test group', () => {
  it('test some stuff', async () => {
    const res = await request(app)
        .get('/your-endpoint')
        .set('Cookie', `myCookie=s:${sign('my value', key)}`);
    expect(res.status).toBe(200);
    // Do other assertions
  });
});
```

Hope that helps : )

Comment: For JSON cookies make sure to stringify before signing. The sign method only takes a string argument. Then change the 's:' prefix to 'j:' and you're good to go.